# Regex to remove div and br at end of contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this have been similarly asked multiple times, but regex is somehow tricky and I can't find my particular need on other answers.

I have this html string:

```
... other content<div><br></div> <div>End of useful html string</div> <div><br></div> <div><br></div> <div><br></div>
```

and this regex pattern:

```
/<div><br><\/div>/gi
```

It matches all `<div><br><\/div>`. Really simple up to that point.

But the thing is that I would like to remove only that pattern **after the end of the useful html string**, in other words, when the pattern starts to be only `<div><br></div> <div><br></div> <div><br></div>` and nothing before `<div>End of useful html string</div>`

Just to clarify, there maybe lots of additional `<div><br></div>` at the end.

This is to remove the new lines at the end of contentEditable div.

Comment: [Don't use Regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/519413). Use a HTML parser and remove the nodes directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to understand your question but.

This will match every `<div><br><\/div>` after `<div>End of string</div>`

```
/(?<=<div>End of string<\/div>.+)<div><br><\/div>/
```

And this will match only the last one in the string:

```
/<div><br><\/div>$/
```

Comment: Sorry I made my best effort to clarify it. "End of string" may be any acceptable HTML besides the pattern <div><br></div>